# Passing html anchor tag value from javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have seen solutions close to my problem but none of them solves it.

Here is my html for the anchor tag:

```
<div class="rating rating2" align="center">         
    <a onclick="myAjax(5)" value="5">★</a>
    <a onclick="myAjax(4)" value="4">★</a>
    <a onclick="myAjax(3)" value="3">★</a>
    <a onclick="myAjax(2)" value="2">★</a>
    <a onclick="myAjax(1)" value="1">★</a> 
</div>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
function myAjax(star) {
    $.ajax({

      url:"find.php",  
      method:"POST", 
      data:{ star : star },
      success: function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
      }
    });
}
```

And my corresponding PHP code in find.php:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['star']))
  {
    $s=$_POST['star'];
    echo $s;
  }

?>
```

And of course I have stored the files in the same directory.I am not getting any output.Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I've tried your example and it works perfectly. console.log show as espected ... according to the clicked anchor ... 1,2,3,4,5 ... I have only copy and paste your code

Comment: Are you including `jQuery`?

Comment: @MTK I meant OP (Muktadir Anzan), but good to know you are too! :)

Comment: @blackandorangecat  sorry ! .. I realized too late that it was not for me. I deleted my comment :D

Comment: including jQuery? as in script link? I did

Comment: Where you expect you going to see the output?

Comment: I am running the codes on a localhost on my browser.

Comment: I would add a error function to your `$.ajax` call as well, and output the error from the backend call. No console logs either? Try naming your parameter `star` to something else, like `num` or something, then use `data: { star : num }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your target is the value attribute  of each link.Hence try something like this.

```
<script>
function myAjax(star) {
$.ajax({

url:"find.php",  
method:"POST", 
data:{ star : star },
success: function( data ) {
console.log( data );
}
});
}

$("a").click(function () {
    var result = $(this).attr('value');

    myAjax(result)
})


</script>
```